# How to align checkboxes horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to **horizontally align the checkboxes** that appear above the dropdowns on the yellow search bar [on this page](http://www.violinschool.org/explore-testing-2/).

I thought that inline block CSS might be the right way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'd be most grateful to know if you have any suggestion of the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I just realised that there are also bullet points appearing there. Does that mean that it's appearing as a bulleted list and I would need to override that?  Hmm

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Comment: The link in the question is not working.

Answer (score 4):

A very modern and flexible solution would be to use flexbox. E.g.:

```
ul.categorychecklist {
    list-style:none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

This is how we do it in 2016 :)
For more details see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.categorychecklist li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Add this code in your CSS file to make the check-boxes inline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes display inline-block is the right way to do this . but you have to add it at the right place 
Please add this in your css

```
 .categorychecklist li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: this code make your checkbox horizontally.

```
ul.categorychecklist {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
ul.categorychecklist li {
     float: left;
     padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
.popular-category {
    display: inline; 
}
```

you may also want to add a `padding-right: 15px;` on the above

Answer (score 0):

For ex. by doing:

```
ul.categorychecklist  { // .categorychecklist - will apply only to this menu
  list-style: none; // remove discs
}
ul.categorychecklist li {
  display: inline-block; // order inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the trick using `float`, as you could see in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/v7thvxjj/2

Note: remember to remove empty `ul` from the HTML code

Comment: Not advisable because it selects all the li elements inside the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will go as follows

```
 <style>
.row-cb {width: 285px;margin: auto; }
.row-cb label { float: left;  }
.row-cb span { float: left; text-align: left; }
.clear-both {clear: both}
</style>

<div class="row-cb">
      <span><input name="option" id="cb1" type="checkbox" /></span>
      <label for="cb1">checkbox-001</label>      
      <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-cb">
      <span><input name="option" id="cb2" type="checkbox" /></span>
      <label for="cb2">checkbox-002</label>

      <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-cb">
      <span><input name="option" id="cb3" type="checkbox" /></span>
      <label for="cb3">checkbox-003</label>

      <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-cb">
      <span><input name="option" id="cb4" type="checkbox" /></span>
       <label for="cb4">checkbox-004</label>

      <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Output will be]

Comment: These are aligned vertically not horizontally